# Can a Window/onunload event be used to dispatch an action in Vue Store

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, event-handling, vuex

I'm trying to add an event listener onunload to dispatch a Vuex store action, letting me know the ID of the window being closed. (This is an app where we need to limit how many tabs are open because of resource consumption - its doing some virtualization/emulation stuff.)

I was able to successfully get a simple onunload event listener firing lifted almost directly from the MDN page on that.

```
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // problem line 
    this.$store.dispatch('CURR_TERMINAL_ACTION', this.id)
  })
```

It seems like the store and the window object aren't going to be able to communicate with each other since I kept getting undefined on store, even when I tried passing it as an argument to this function thinking maybe I could provide access that way.

On a related note: I had thought that maybe I could try to accomplish this with a destruction lifecycle hook oF Vue, instead. (beforeDestroy(), probably.) However, each time this component is launched, it gets launched into a new browser tab. When I close out of that tab, it doesn't appear to trigger component destruction. After looking at the docs, it looks like you manually have to destroy components, otherwise they only get unmounted. I don't think my original onunload event can interact with $destroy either, if it can't access $store.

Comment: what `this` refers to in your problem line?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `this` refers to window, or something but your `vue-component`. Then, you need to create another variable to get your `vue-component`reference.

```
let that = this
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // problem line 
    that.$store.dispatch('CURR_TERMINAL_ACTION', that.id)
})
```